# How to put flash content over the html even if the flash is not

Tags: html, flash

So, if you go to MySpace for example (http://www.myspace.com/sonidolalimpia) you see now the logo have a very interesting effect when you put your mouse over, how they did this?

Comment: That site appears to have very limited Flash content.  Are you sure you don't want CSS information?

Comment: I found the mouseover effect described only on the main page (http://www.myspace.com) at the logo in the top left corner (takes a while to load, try moving your mouse over and out some times)

Comment: I guess it's a combo of Flash, JavaScript and HTML/CSS where the logo images is overlaid with a Flash animation, once the swf file is fully loaded, swf files like this one: http://cms.myspacecdn.com/cms/x/11/3/eyeplant.swf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already was written, all trick not in the flash, but in the css and jQuery. They uses jQuery onMouseOver Event and simply switch the picture version of the logo with a transparent flash one.

before

```
<h2>    
    <a href="/" class="MSIcon MSLogo" id="msStaticLogo" style="left: 0pt;">
        Myspace
    </a>
</h2>   

<div id="flashLogoContainer">
    <a href="/">
    <span id="logoInTrigger">   
    Myspace 
    </span>
    </a>
    <object width="354" height="475" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
            data="http://cms.myspacecdn.com/cms/x/11/3/bag.swf" id="msFlashLogos" 
        style="visibility: visible; top: -28px; left: -9999px;">
    <param name="quality" value="high">
    <param name="wmode" value="transparent">
    <param name="bgcolor" value="transparent">
    <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always">
    </object>
    <span class="MSIcon beta" id="beta">Beta</span>
    <div id="leftLogoTrigger" style="display: none;"></div>
    <div id="rightLogoTrigger" style="display: none;"></div>    
    <div id="bottomLogoTrigger" style="display: none;"></div>   
</div>
</li>
```

after

```
 <li class="logo">
<h2>    
    <a href="/" class="MSIcon MSLogo" id="msStaticLogo" style="left: -9999px;">
        Myspace
    </a>
</h2>   

<div id="flashLogoContainer">
    <a href="/">
    <span id="logoInTrigger">   
    Myspace 
    </span>
    </a>
    <object width="354" height="475" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
            data="http://cms.myspacecdn.com/cms/x/11/3/bag.swf" id="msFlashLogos"
        style="visibility: visible; top: -28px; left: -120px;">
    <param name="quality" value="high">
    <param name="wmode" value="transparent">
    <param name="bgcolor" value="transparent">
    <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always">
    </object>
    <span class="MSIcon beta" id="beta">Beta</span>
    <div id="leftLogoTrigger" style="display: block;"></div>
    <div id="rightLogoTrigger" style="display: block;"></div>   
    <div id="bottomLogoTrigger" style="display: block;"></div>  
</div>
</li>
```